# VBA Define Dynamic Name Range

Tags: vba, excel, dynamic, range

I'm looking at a way in which to **name/rename a range** based on an adjacent cell value that can change due to sorting/value change, etc. via VBA.

I've tried to outline an example of how the grid is laid out. This is all contained is a pre-defined table. The `Yes/No` columns contain the condition. If the value is `Y` then I want the cell to the right of it to be included in the named range.

I've had a look at various dynamic named range queries suggesting the use of OFFSET but I'm struggling to code it in a way that's getting me anywhere.

```
        Column1 Column2  Column3 Column4

Row1    Y/N1    Balance1 Y/N2    Balance2
Row2    Y       1.000    Y       5.000
Row3    Y       2.000    N       0.000
Row4    N       0.000    N       0.000
Row5    Y       3.000    N       0.000
Row6    Y       4.000    N       0.000
```

Comment: So in your example, you want a named range for column2 (and 4) that would be `B2:B3` - or `B2:B3;B5:B6`? The former is possible with formulas, the latter only with VBA.

Comment: That latter. Based on my above example, the range would be (B2:B3,B5:B6,D2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I've figured out the answer. Not sure if it's the most efficient but it appears to be performing as expected.

```
Sub GetRange()
Dim rngselect As Range, rngfinal As Range, cell As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set rngselect = ws.Range("$A:$A,$C:$C")

For Each cell In rngselect
    If cell.Value = "Y" Then
        If rngfinal Is Nothing Then
            Set rngfinal = ws.Range(Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column + 1).Address)
        Else
            Set rngfinal = Application.Union(rngfinal, ws.Range(Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column + 1).Address))
        End If
    End If
Next cell

Names.Add Name:="test", RefersTo:=rngfinal End Sub
```

Comment: If it works, it works :) +1 to solve your own question.